# Regex Replace Between &quot; Encoding

Tags: regex, text, replace, regex-lookarounds

I want to be able to replace `style=&quot;STUFF&quot;`

I keep thinking that this is the correct REGEX:

```
style=(&quot;)(?!&quot;)*(&quot;)
```

But for some reason that won't match.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `style=&quot;(.*?)&quot;` instead.

Comment: @Dav, you nailed it. @Eric Hendrickson, the `?` after the `.*` makes the `*` "ungreedy". Meaning, it will match to the nearest closing `&qout;`.